# page.render('/dev/stdout') does not work in windows 7 using phantomjs-prebuilt 2.1.13

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am trying to render to stdout using this function:

```
page.render('/dev/stdout');
```

Unfortunately it did not work for me, I am running node 6.9.1 on windows 7 using phantomjs-prebuilt 2.1.13.

Regards.

Comment: It might work under the windows 10 bash subsystem or cygwin. It will definitely work under a linux VM.

Comment: Yeah, but I @pguardiario I am running this in a windows 7 machine

Answer (score 1):

> `/dev/stdout` does not exist in `Windows`, only in `Linux`. `Windows` has no direct equivalent to `/dev/stdout`. Read [SuperUser Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/241272/windows-how-to-redirect-file-parameter-to-stdout-windows-equivalent-of-dev-s)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I realize doing a console.log({foo: mightyObject}); in node writes to stdout, is not a clean solution but works.